# Change Meta Title seperator and remove on homepage

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, title

I'm trying to change the character which is used as a seperator in my page title.
At present it is in the format

> Site Name - Page Title

However I would like to change this hyphen to a pipe character

> Site Name | Page Title

I can't an option to do this in the back end.
How can I achieve this effect?
My site is using woocommerce, so in the `header.php` file in the title meta tags it is `<?php woo_title(''); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<?php woo_title(''); ?>
```

with

```
<?php woo_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?>
```